# Call Script Dont Wait For Response

Tags: python, http, proxy

My Windows application needs to call a script but it doesn't need to wait for a response. Its just posting data in the Query String of the url. For speed I dont want to wait for the response and I am not getting anything from the server just sending.

Does the below code call a script on the server and NOT wait for the response? Or is `opener.open()` blocking (sending a HTTP request and waiting for the response)?

```
proxy               = urllib2.ProxyHandler()
opener              = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
in_                 = opener.open( "www.mysite.com/a.py?data=somedata )
```

Note: The data I am sending is through the query string. So the HTTP Request should be a `GET` afaik. Maybe I should `POST` the data? Using `Request.add_data()`. Would that mean that I dont have to wait for a response? I am using a `ProxyHandler` for users who may be behind a proxy. Will a `POST` still work if they are behind a proxy - this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request.add_data) suggests only the `HTTPHandler` will work.

Comment: If you don't want it to wait, use a thread instead. https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Comment: Just letting you know you're missing a quote at the end of your last line. I'd fix it for you but I can't do 1 char edits

Comment: You'll want to do a thread as suggested because otherwise you don't "know" that the receiving server accepted and processed your request. My suggestion would be to thread and then if you really want to cut down on resources quit after you start to receive data which will at least contain your status so you know if it succeeded (200 OK) or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that contains your HTTP request and call it with a thread which will run it in the background.

You can pass args to the args variable.

```
from threading import Thread

def makeReq():
    proxy               = urllib2.ProxyHandler()
    opener              = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
    in_                 = opener.open( "www.mysite.com/a.py?data=somedata" )

thread = Thread(target = makeReq, args=())
thread.start()
```